# Using Python class files in QML

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qml, qt-creator

I have a `main.qml` file that look like below

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5


ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    TextField {
        id:textarea
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        Button {
            text: "Click Me"
            anchors.leftMargin: 34
            id:textareabutton
            y: 0
            anchors.left:textarea.right
            onClicked: {
                someclass.say(textarea.text)
            }
        }
    }
    TextField {
        id:textarea2
        anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: 0
        anchors.topMargin: 37
        anchors.top: textarea.bottom
        anchors.horizontalCenter: textarea.horizontalCenter
    }
    Connections {
        target: someclass

        onToPython : {
            textarea2.text = say
        }
    }
}
```

i have a python class file which i have added using add file option in `qtcreator`, when i run `main.qml` i am getting errors related to the classes being undefined as below

```
qrc:/main.qml:33:5: QML Connections: Cannot assign to non-existent property "onToPython"
qrc:/main.qml:34: ReferenceError: someclass is not defined
qrc:/main.qml:22: ReferenceError: someclass is not defined
```

I have the `external tools` configured in the Qt creator for python  and when i run through it,it works. However it is not working when i run `main.qml`. What am i missing, how can i make use of the python class file.

below is the python file that invokes the QML , if i run from python it works, i want to run qml file and invoke this class

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject,pyqtSignal,pyqtSlot

class someclassr(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)

    toPython=pyqtSignal(str, arguments=["say"])
    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def say (self,name):
        word= "hi " + name
        self.toPython.emit(word)


app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
engine=QQmlApplicationEngine()
classloader=someclassr()
engine.rootContext().setContextProperty('someclass',classloader)
engine.load('main.qml')
engine.quit.connect(app.quit)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Shouldn’t `someclass` be `someobject` instead? You connect to class instances, not class objects (a Python concept).

Comment: use qmlRegisterType method. https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/qml.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: There's no built-in integration between QML and Python. I'm not sure why one'd assume that there was, but there really isn't. Qt Creator is a multi-language IDE, and its support for Python doesn't imply that QML and Python are integrated.

Having said that, Python classes can be easily [integrated with Qt and QML using PyQt](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/qml.html). If you don't want to depend on PyQt, you can integrate the two manually by writing adapter classes that call into the Python runtime that your application would link with.

Comment: Actually i am using PyQt5 in my class

Comment: Provide a complete example, then. The “you’re using” phrase means something else for everyone: obviously you’re not “using” it because it would work then. So we’d need to see exactly how you “use” PyQt.

Comment: @Techiesoft As noted Kuba Ober Qt Creator currently only serves to edit Python files, but is not able to create projects that use Python and QML at the same time would generally recognize the interaction between both parties as there is currently between C ++ and QML. So the answer is: nothing is missing because Qt Creator does not currently have that capacity, maybe if you report it as a bug to Qt Creator in the future it will be built and add that functionality to the editor

Comment: @eyllanesc how can i test an application written in QML and python for desktop and android then :(

Comment: @Techiesoft Well, there is no tool to do testing between qml and python nowadays, maybe it is the opportunity that you create the tool. maybe with pytest

Comment: @eyllanesc does it mean i cannot build apps for android with python and QML? :-o

Comment: @Techiesoft  You have to use pyqtdeploy: https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqtdeploy/intro, One thing is the testing tool and another a deployment tool

Comment: @eyllanesc have you ever used pyqtdeploy for android? i am struggling to make it work :(